# Removing unused resources requires unused code shrinking to be turned on

Tags: android, android-resources, shrinkresources

I am preparing to release an App to production. So, I generated signed apk. After generating signed apk,  I was getting a problem. My apk file size is a little large and I tried ways to shrink the apk size. I already tried

> app --> Refactor --> Remove Unused Resources

and it is not too reduce. So, I added **shrinkResources true** in my build.gradle(app)

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

After adding **shrinkResources true** and I got below error when I rebuild. My question is how should I turn on unused Code shrinking first? Thanks and appreciating.

[image]

Comment: *probably* `minifyEnabled true`

Comment: With technical stuff, shrinkResources works only when you have set minfyEnabled to true

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Resource shrinking works only in conjunction with code shrinking. After the code shrinker removes all unused code, the resource shrinker can identify which resources the app still uses. This is especially true when you add code libraries that include resources—you must remove unused library code so the library resources become unreferenced and, thus, removable by the resource shrinker

To enable resource shrinking, set the shrinkResources property to true in your build.gradle file (alongside minifyEnabled for code shrinking). For example:

```
 android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

[reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#shrink-resources)

Comment: I've got `minifyEnabled true` but still getting the error

Comment: @Muganwas same here, I'm also facing same problem, how you resolved it.

Comment: @Vasanth I don't think I did, I must have just given up.

Comment: For me, it was the order of the codes, changing it to 
```         release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }``` cleared all errors

Comment: minifyEnabled has to be true if you are willing to apply shrinkResources true

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you set by mistake `minifyEnabled = false` and `shrinkResources = true` in your buildTypes.debug, so, maybe, it is a root of a problem, not your buildTypes.release

Answer (score 6):

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }
}﻿
```

Answer (score 4):

You might want to refer to the Android Documentation to shrink your code and resources:

[Shrink your code and resources](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code)

Like a comment already pointed out, resource shrinking only works when you have used the code shrinker. To enable `shrinkResources` in your `build.gradle` file you must have first set `minifyEnabled` to `true`

Answer (score 2):

Simple just open the build.gradle file on App level i.e. android/app/build.gradle and implement this:

```
 release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        useProguard true
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' 

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use resource shrinking, you also need to enable code shrinking as they both works in conjunction.
So to do so, set **shrinkResources true** along with **minifyEnabled true**.
You can follow the [official site](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code?utm_source=android-studio#shrink-resources) for the same.

Answer (score 1):

make sure to add it into proper part of gradle

```
   signingConfigs {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "java.util.Date", "buildTime", "new java.util.Date(" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "L)"
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "java.util.Date", "buildTime", "new java.util.Date(" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "L)"
        }
    }
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have added `shrinkResources true` make sure it comes after `minifyEnabled true` the order matters so https://stackoverflow.com/a/56426634/10355668 is correct thanks

Answer (score 0):

set minifyEnabled to true
in both debug and release

Answer (score 0):

Check these variations if this error occurs:

1. `shrinkResources = true` works only with `minifyEnabled = true`
2. There is `minifyEnabled = true` in your BuildType of apk (often minifyEnabled turned on only for release, if you will try to build apk for debug it error occurs )
3. Try to check is there extra `minifyEnabled = false` that could override your `minifyEnabled = true`

Then try to Sync project with gradle files and rebuild project