# Can I build two APKs without doing source minifaction twice when only resources differ?

Tags: android, gradle

Minification is the build step that takes the most time in our build pipeline. We have two APKs that only differ slighly - branded differently with different XML assets. Would it be possible to change the gradle build flow so that two different APKs were compiled with different asset sets, but the source code compile and minification steps would only be run once? Right now we are set up with two modules which results in the minification step being run twice.

Comment: Can you describe the build config of the project a little? e.g. are there actually two different modules and not just different flavors?

Comment: @tbadams they are two different modules now yes. They differ by some XML assets and a handful o Kotlin clases (mainly different dependency injection setup). Some of the XMLs are secrets belonging to either of the recepients so creating just one APK that skins itself runtime is a no-go.

Comment: Ah ok.  It's been a while for me but you should still be able to control which app gets which secret using flavors.  It probably doesn't make a difference however, in a quick test flavors are also being shrunk separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be an option for this.  [Android Developer's description](https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code) that "Resource shrinking works only in conjunction with code shrinking" implies they're tightly coupled, and shrinking does in fact require code minify to work ([stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52310841/removing-unused-resources-requires-unused-code-shrinking-to-be-turned-on)).  And since each build variant / output module has its own chain of shrinking tasks there's logically no way to tell R8 to share results without disabling it altogether.